# Set Unique proxy per tab in chromium

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, chromium, google-chrome-devtools, source-code

I am trying to customize chromium-browser such that each tab in the browser has a unique proxy, so connections from one tab do not appear to come from the same IP as another tab.

I used chrome.proxy.settings.set from chrome developer API to set the proxy for a tab, but the problem with this method is that it set the proxy for entire chrome, correct me if I am wrong. So when I open a new tab and set the proxy in that tab, it will change the proxy of previous tabs. Also, as I already mentioned, it set the proxy for the entire chrome.

I think there is no way to handle this using plugins/extensions, and it can only be handled by doing some modifications in chromium source code. But again, chromium source code has too many files and millions of lines of code. There are some chromium-based browsers like a ghost, insomniac, which can implement the same thing, and I guess they did so by modifying source code.

Do i need some help to which file or section of chromium source code should I look into and perform some modifications or any other solution? Please help me. I am working on it for a few months, but understanding and debug such a large source code is not easy.

Comment: This is a much needed feature particularly for users in China.

Comment: Do you have any workaround for this problem?

Comment: Ghost browser does support this feature. Chrome doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this excellent extension to set different proxies based on domain or urls: [Proxy Switchy Auto](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchy-auto/bnhejmehblohhaalgnnohedpijgkjeof)

Supports Chrome and all chromium based browers like Opera and Microsoft edge